# Is it possible to reload a page only if it's reach a specific breakpoint?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a webpage where 2 different event happening.I set one to only execute if window.innerWidth < 767 and I set the another the same but if its window.innerWidth > 767.The Code is working,as long as I start resizing between the two.If I start over 767 and shrinking the another get it's effect and vice versa.But when I refresh the page once everything is fine.

Tried setting local and sessionStorages but its not really working as I imagined...

I have something like this:

```
$(window).resize(function(){
  if(window.innerWidth < 767 || window.innerWidth > 767)
    location.reload();
})
```

I want to reload the page once when it's enter on of these areas and not reload again until its reach the another area.

Thanks for the answer beforehand!

Comment: If you only want the refresh to trigger when the width passes the threshold in a certain direction you will need to check the width on page load and save it (or a flag of some sort) in a variable and use that inside your `resize` handler. However, it seems likely you probably don't actually need to be doing this... why do you want to reload the page when it gets resized in that way?

Comment: I'm not really want to make this way but from all the things I tried this one sort of worked so I stick with it.But if there's a handier way to do what I want to achive,I'm all ears!:)

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you want something like this:

```
if(!window.localStorage.getItem('page_size')){
    window.localStorage.setItem('page_size', 'big');
}

$(window).resize(function(){
    if(window.innerWidth < 767 || window.localStorage.getItem('page_size') == 'big'){
        window.localStorage.setItem('page_size', 'small');
        location.reload();
    }
    if(window.innerWidth > 767 || window.localStorage.getItem('page_size') == 'small'){
        window.localStorage.setItem('page_size', 'big');
        location.reload();
    }
});
```

Comment: I tried something similiar but less set localStorage so I try this out,Thanks!:)